# Automated testing of Oracle Forms

Tags: automated-testing, tools

What is the best test automation tool you'd recommend for testing Oracle Forms and why? Assuming a Windows desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

Testing Your Oracle ADF Faces Application with Selenium
How to use Selenium and JUnit together to build unit tests that test Oracle Application Development Framework Web UIs

By John Stegeman

Published March 2010

Downloads:

Oracle JDeveloper Studio Edition
Selenium
Sample app (HR Schema install required)
Oracle Database XE (if needed)
In addition to testing individual components and pieces of code, it is important to test that the user interface (UI) of a Web application functions as expected. Traditionally, this type of user interface testing is done by real people sitting in front of a computer manually running test scripts to verify that things work correctly. However, manually executing UI testing has some drawbacks:

Manual testing takes longer than UI testing because people are inherently slower than computers.
People can make mistakes running manual tests.
Manual testing can be expensive—it requires salaries.
You may not be able to run manual UI testing as often as you like due to the lack of enough testers.
[For more details check here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/adf/part6-094560.html)

Comment: Welcome to SQA. The idea of this site is that users will provide knowledge and details from their own experience other that just copying content from other sites. Have a look at some questions that have been voted up to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with both OracleExtendedSelenium and QTP Oracle Plugin for ADF based application. The basic pros and cons would be same as in general. 
For ADF Faces specific purpose I could not find any reason why a QTP shop would choose Selenium or vice versa. I would go with the tool which my QA is experienced in.

Answer (score 0):

Im using Sikuli for enterprise level Oracle forms deployments.  It can be a bit fiddly when validating small details and it can't really handle verifying quantity/price box values etc but when combined with jdbc etc to validate the value it is very useful